# I want help to explain boxplot

Tags: boxplot

I want help to explain this boxplot

[image]

I generated data from this code

`set.seed(1234); a4 = matrix(rnorm(10*200, 1,1), 200); boxplot(a4)`

I only see 10 samples although I generated 200 samples, can one help me to understand this boxplot

Thank you

Comment: your code generates a matrix of 10 columns, each column has 200 rows. The boxplot function in R will plot each column in a boxplot when given a matrix. Thats why you are only seeing 10 boxplots. This seems more like a question for stack overflow if its solely about R programming

Comment: @MikeKatz45 Perhaps it should be migrated. Even so, it appears that you have answered the question. Please post the relevant parts as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments, what you are doing with your current code is generating 2000 values with gaussian probability (mean and standard deviation of 1) and putting them in a matrix with 200 rows. By default, the [matrix](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/matrix) function in R will fill the matrix by columns. So your first 200 values will be in the first column, values 201 to 400 in the second, etc. This results in a matrix with 10 columns total.

R's `boxplot` function will plot a boxplot for each column of a matrix if you give it one. That being said, if what you want is to have 200 columns (each with 10 values) to produce 200 boxplots you should do:

```
boxplot(matrix(rnorm(10*200, 1,1), nrow = 10, ncol = 200))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I want to add set.seed(1234) in your code how can that add

Comment: 1. type your `set.seed(1234)` in. 2. Then hit <enter> or equivalent. 3. Then paste Mike's code in. This is not the right place for elementary R help, though.